# Variable variables CakePHP and 'set' in View

Tags: php, cakephp

Ok, so I have a list of 'TLDs' that I want to loop through and create a chart for in PHP.

I want to look up each TLD and use the name of that TLD as the variable.  I.e. yahoo.com would be $yahoocom, so that I can create charts for all "TLDs" in the database.

My code:

```
        $tld = $this->Report->getTLDs();

    foreach($tld as $row){

        $tld = str_replace('.','', $row['inboxer_tlds']['tld_name'] . 'openchart'); //yahoocomopenchart

        $$tld = new GoogleCharts();

        $$tld->type("PieChart");
        $$tld->options(array('title' => "Opens Stats for ". $row['inboxer_tlds']['tld_name']));
        $$tld->columns(array(
            'tld' => array(
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'tld'
            ),
            'number' => array(
                'type' => 'number',
                'label' => 'number'
            )
        ));

        $$tld->addRow(array('tld' => $row['inboxer_tlds']['tld_name'], 'number' => $junk['0']['0']['COUNT(*)']));

        $this->set(compact('tld'));
    }
```

First of all, am I using the variable variables right?  I'm getting this error:

get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object

I 'thought' $$tld should equal to $yahoocom ?

and finally, is it possible to 'set' in the view?  Normally you would just do set(compact('variable')), but since there is no dollar sign, ...I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's looks a little weird to me, I would ditch that and use an array with the TLD names as keys instead.

Somethiing like this (note that I've also changed the variable names and stuff in order to make it a little cleaner):

```
$tlds = $this->Report->getTLDs();

$charts = array();
foreach($tlds as $tld) {

    $name = $tld['inboxer_tlds']['tld_name'];

    $chart = new GoogleCharts();

    $chart->type('PieChart');
    $chart->options(array('title' => 'Opens Stats for ' . $name));
    $chart->columns(array(
        'tld' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'tld'
        ),
        'number' => array(
            'type' => 'number',
            'label' => 'number'
        )
    ));

    $chart->addRow(array('tld' => $name, 'number' => $junk['0']['0']['COUNT(*)']));

    $charts[$name] = $chart;
}

$this->set(compact('charts'));
```

So you would end up with the variable named `charts` in your view, containing a structure like:

```
Array
(
    [google.com] => GoogleCharts Object
    [yahoo.com] => GoogleCharts Object
    ...
)
```

For the sake of completeness, you can use dynamic variables with `compact` by passing the name as a variable, ie

```
compact($tld)
```

Also you could create the array for `set()` manually:

```
$this->set(array($tld => $$tld));
```

or pass two parameters, the first is the name, the second the value:

```
$this->set($tld, $$tld);
```